# Tasmotizing D1 mini fails with Permission error

Tags: esp8266, tasmota

I've spent several hours trying to tasmotize a D1 mini. I've connected it to my Dell XPS 15 9500 Win11 Pro using a known good (and tried half a dozen other "known good") usb cable. The XPS recognizes the USB device on COM5, and identifies it as "USB SERIAL CH340 (COM5)", so I assume that eliminates the cable as the problem.

When I hit the Tasmotize button, I get an error:
"Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)"

Google tells me this is an issue with my USB driver, so I installed the driver recommended, rebooted, and tried again. No joy. I also did try another D1 mini, right outa the bag. No joy.

Any ideas?